# How to Reset ELAM (early launch antimalware) configuration on windows 10, corrupted driver can't be uninstalled

Tags: windows-10, boot, anti-virus

I have a windows 10 machine, up to date on all patches, but a corrupted ELAM driver from a previous installation of an antivirus. I have removed all of the AVs except windows defender and the elam list still shows four drivers to be loaded (wdboot plus mbam and what I believe was avira).

I have broken the failed automatic repair reboot loop, but the only way I can get the machine to boot is by changing startup options each time (it is ignoring the setting in the BCD configuration) to bypass early launch malware detection at boot time every time I boot. The log file tells me that boot file protected_elam.sys is missing or corrupted (I have renamed it and the backup copy to no avail).

So my question is this, is there a way to wipe the ELAM configuration heap and put a fresh wdboot.sys in place without doing either a windows re-install or windows reset. The thought of reinstalling all my software after a reset makes me reluctant to do that if there is another way.

From what I have read, a reset without a wipe will "remove any third party antivirus", delete office and delete SOME of my other applications... Not very reassuring

I can't find any answers as to whether "Bootfix.exe" will reset the ELAM hive or not. (I would suspect not)

I even tried reinstalling avira, but with ELAM disabled (the only way it boots) and/or the current version of avira, it does not seem to do anything to the elam driver.

Any assistance on cleaning up a corrupted ELAM configuration is highly appreciated

Comment: If this were mine, I would just do a format and fresh install. Might be faster in the long run.

Comment: not helpful.  Software reinstallation is probably 40 to 80 hours after windows is reinstalled.

Comment: Have you attempted to disable Secure Boot. It’s required by Microsoft which means Dell is required to offer a way to disable it.  This will at least allow or should in theory boot the device normally.  You probably don’t have a discrete TPM but a fTPM.  If you can boot normally you can try a in-place reinstall allowing you to avoid reinstalling applications

Comment: secure boot happens before ELAM loads, I am getting past that part, it is the elam  (not in the boot track) which is digitally signed by microsoft only  (irrespective of the antivirus vendor supplying it) and the decryption/validation keys and logic are all stored in the elam heap).   I have to select option 8 to skip loading elam at boot time, and the machine boots every time. https://hal.science/hal-03088315/document  https://nostarch.com/download/samples/Rootkits_Ch6_Sample.pdf (page 79 shows sequence of what secure boot does, before the kernel is loaded and before ELAM).

Comment: I worked out a faster approach to reinstall. Up and running the first day and then do the remainder as I am working with the computer. Computer running is better than not running properly.

Comment: For future reference: there are tools to remove an AV, either from the manufacturer or elsewhere. See https://support.avira.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003162153-Uninstallation-of-Avira-for-Windows for Avira, and https://www.selecthub.com/resources/how-to-uninstall-avast/ for Avast!, as examples. As you state, if you try removing it manually, it may make removal difficult to complete.

Comment: Trust but verify.  When I removed, Avira, Avast and malwarebytes, I used their uninstall routines and received no errors (over the course of several years of owning this computer).  Imagine my surprise when trying to solve this problem I looked into the ELAMBKUP and windows drivers  directory (where autorepair goes to restore elam drivers) and found that there were drivers from all three there.  Then tracing the boot log to see that one that was supposed to have been uninstalled had failed.  Uninstalls have been incomplete and I am just trying wipe the elam config without reinstalling windows.